# can I remove dimmed-colored properties in settings.json file in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Image of settings.json]

There are dimmed properties in my `settings.json` file. Are they dimmed because they are not being used? Can I safely remove them?

Comment: In general yes, this probably means these settings don't really exist - but I don't know for 100% sure.

Comment: You know I added an answer, but I deleted it. That is odd that those settings are showing up as being dimmed

Comment: Do you have some of the built-in extensions disabled?

Comment: Honestly, it looks like you disabled the git extension that VS Code ships with

Comment: I did disable some extensions. I installed some and uninstalled some too.

Comment: Okay, well, the fact that your asking this question shows that you don't fully understand the implications of what you have done. Its disabled core features that you were using. That's why the settings are dimmed, because VS Code can't reach them. Those settings were added because you enabled features that use them in the settings view. So basically, you enabled features to use them, then uninstalled the fundamental software that adds support for them, IDK if your following, but it doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: You ask if you can safely remove them, but they are dimmed because you already removed them. And I think it is safe to disable the 
"Built-in Git Extension", but I can't confirm that. If you are adding code to a repository, and have stashed commits, or code added, but not commited, you could risk deleting it. There are other built-in extensions that I can confirm, are not safe to remove. For your own sake, research extensions before you get install/uninstall happy about it. Though, sometimes F'ing up software is the best way to learn about it, I really do believe that.

Comment: If you can break something, you can give your self a reason to fix it, and once you know how something breaks, and how it gets fixed, you have an understanding of the system, from there you can start building your own systems. anyway, thats what I was told once, and I always thought that in the right context their is alot of truth to that.

Comment: Unreachable settings is a good way to describe this.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**
Yes, it is safe to delete settings that have a dimmed-out color. Just to be sure you can check if you have the Git and Prettier extensions installed/uninstalled as it seems those extensions have dimmed-out `settings.json` file.

**Reasoning:**
Well in your case, and as @j D3V mentioned, you've disabled or uninstalled the git extension. This means that any settings related to or needed by the extension will be dimmed-out and are no longer required.

I was surfing the web and testing out stuff in my VSCode, and I found a setting in my `settings.json` file that too, was dimmed out:

[image]

The dimmed out setting is `"color-highlight.markerType": "dot-before",`. This is because I no longer have the extension that used this setting, the extension was named 'Color Highlight':
[image]

In the image above, you can see I no longer have the installed extension, however, I once did. Basically, the settings are dimmed-out because they were related to an extension you no longer have installed. Thus it is safe to delete them. If you keep the settings, that's perfectly fine too!

Answer (score 1):

### I seen this question when you first posted it, but something was odd.

#### So the Properties that are Dimmed, Should Be interpreted as "Unreachable by the Control-flow"

In other words, the are unnecessary, and VS Code cannot make use of them.

The editor can be configured to change how dim — *or "how opaque"* — the code that is *"unnecessary"* renders. Its a theme property that changes the dimness. I included the configuration to use in your `settings.json` file below.

###### NOTE: _The setting uses a base-16 color format, much like you often will see in CSS, or SVG, however, it must have an 8 or 4 digit hex-color as to properly set the transparency. If an eight digit number is used, the first 6 digits are ignored, if a 4 digit is used then the first 3 are ignored. Below is an example of a properly configured configuration for changing how dim "Unreachable Code" renders *(aka "unnecessary code")*.

```
  {
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#00000080"
    }
  }
```

---

#### Its Important to Know Why Code isn't Being Reached

These types of details should always be obvious, if not, something might be wrong, and it is worth investigating. When I first took a look at the image you included *(of your `settings.json` file)* I immediately noticed something was off. There were settings that were part of the core, fundamental features that are built-in to VS Code. The settings are contributed through "built-in extensions". The only way they could be dim, is if you disabled one or more built-in extension.

**First Let me state**, you should never disable VS Codes core extensions that are built-into the editor. If you do, you can't expect the [official VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to pertain to your editor, you can't expect that other questions on stack overflow will work as the authors intend for them to work, you will also loose many of the features and abilities that make VS Code such a powerful tool.

You should enable the built-in extensions that you disabled.
[image]

Comment: Helpful post but I it seems to me that anything really "core" and "built-in" would not be in an extension that can be disabled or uninstalled. For instance, I don't have any git extensions - but the basic git tools are all available to me for pushing, pulling, stashing, etc. Emmet once used to be an extension but no longer is - it seems to have become one of those built-in features.

Comment: @topsail A `git` extension is built-in to vscode.  Search ofr `@builtin` in the Extensions search input.  It can be disabled but not uninstalled.  I suppose it can be disabled because you might be using some other version control than git and aren't interested in it.

Comment: @topsail IDK how you come to the conclusion that you have, (because of the way something seems?) You've obviously used Windows & Apple proprietary software for your entire existence. VS Code is a highly configurable, opensource development tool. You most certainly can disable the extensions. Mark is right, you can't uninstall them, but you absolutely can disable them. And this comment isn't so much for, you, as it is for the next guy reading this thread. Disabling the built-in extensions will cause problems, it will cause fundamental features to not work.

Comment: I mean you had your file-highlighting disabled, such that when a file was modified or added or deleted, VSC SCM/Git features wouldn't highlight that, and you didn't even realize it.

Comment: Got it - thanks. Now I am better educated on VSCode built in extensions!

Comment: @all In my case unsed lines in VSCode setting.json are not dimmed. I have almost fresh install with minimal changes. How can I get it dimmed? I tried `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#00000080" }` but it is not working. Why in almost default setting dimming of "dead" items does not work?

Comment: The settings that are for extensions you have disabled, or do not have, are what is being dimmed in the image. The __`"git.decoration.enabled": false`__ is showing you that if the git extension is disabled then the setting for it will be dimmed. Also, I assume your using a light theme, otherwise #00000080 might be hard to see.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV Found problem why dimming was not working at all! I have mklinked user profile and extensions dir and this mkliniking caused this bug that inactive items was not dimmed. Mklinks are really not reliable. E.g. Chrome and Google drive sync apps does not work correctly when mklinked to another location.